# Send push notification to all user phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova, push-notification

i'm trying to send a notification to all my users with phone. I'm using a GCM and phonegap push plugin. I save a registrationId in database and then I write this 2 function and I work with soap web service. The notification are not send.
This is my code. The function:

```
function sendPush($registrationId, $title, $message) {
    $registrationIds = array(
        $registrationId
    );
    $msg = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        'vibrate' => 1,
        'sound' => 1

        // you can also add images, additionalData

    );
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
        'data' => $msg
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key='.
        'AIzaSyD-sL8HiKyKRWdwxVMmTMYgkqOgVGOiNP8',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === false) die('Curl failed '.curl_error());
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function push() {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testf', 'root', '');
    $sql = "select * from client";
    $texte = '<table>';

    // $texte=array();

    foreach($db - > query($sql) as $data) {
        $texte = $texte.
        '#'.$data["regId"];
    }

    $texte = $texte;
    return $texte;
}
```

The call is:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/fou/server.php');
$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$result = $client->call('push');
//echo $result;
$x = explode("#", $result);
$nb = count($x);


for ($i = 0; $i < $v; $i++) {
    $resp = $client->call('sendPush', array('registrationId' => $x[$i], 'titre' => $title, 'message' => $message));
    print_r($resp);
}
```

Comment: are you getting a response JSON from google in $result ?

Comment: no, I don't get a response from $result

Comment: you must've getting something. I can see you are not printing or logging the value of $result.please print/log it and share the output.

Comment: I do a print but no result on output. " $var= $client->call('sendPush',array('registrationId'=>$x[$i],'title'=>$title,'message'=>$message));
  print_r($var);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

PushNotification.php

```
<?php

    $message = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];

    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";

    // Connect
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo-me", $user, $pass);
    define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyD-sL8HiKyKRWdwxVMmTMYgkqOgVGOiNP8');

    $msg = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        'vibrate' => 1,
        'sound' => 1
    );

    $query = "SELECT regId FROM client";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    // set array
    $registrationIds = array();


    // look through query
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // add each row returned into an array
        $registrationIds[] = $row;
    }

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
        'data' => $msg,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key='.API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

And call that `php` file from `cordova` application like:

```
http://yoururl.com/PushNotification.php?msg=test&title=LoremIpsum
```

So in this case, it will retrieve all registrationId from your table and it will send notification to all that devices.

**Edit 1:**

Use this code in your application.

```
//Getting value of title textbox
var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
//Getting value of message textbox
var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'http://yoururl.com/PushNotification.php?title='+title+'&msg='+message,
    success: function(data){
        alert("Success: " + data);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a form to write a message and title, i edit your code. I delete the 2 first line. I work wit pdo, i write "   $query = "SELECT regId FROM client";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
// set array
$registrationIds = array();


// look through query
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // add each row returned into an array
    $registrationIds[] = $row;
}     "  and i call "  $var= $client->call('sendPush',array('title'=>$title,'message'=>$message))
  echo $var;"  i have an error unexpected 'echo'

Comment: I got a error in call of function when to print the result of function. this my call  http://pastebin.com/hysvRssU

Comment: But I can't understand why you are using SOAP? You just pass your message and title directly to the function by getting data from form.

Comment: I use SOAP because my application is developped with SOAP and php. did you mean i don't integrate my function in my SOAP server

Comment: Yes. Directly call your `php` file with form's serialize method. So, it will post your all values like msg & title.

Comment: Sorry, can give to me an example

Comment: Please make one thing clear. Do you want to send notification from app's form or web form? So I can give example accordingly.

Comment: I send a notification from phone to phone. In my phone application, i have a form with title an message input text because the notification are editable.

Comment: Just keep PushNotification.php file with same code mentioned above and add above edited code at application side. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I have this error " {muticast_id":23455666,"success":0,"failure":12,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"invalidRegistration"} " I think i must verify my registrationId saved in database.... Thanks @Dhruv